# Will consumers in a group subscribe to one topic each, if there is a single partition per topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Debezium to log changes in my database, and Debezium generates change events in a topic for each table that exists in my database.These change records are consumed to populate another database.

If I restrict each topic to only have 1 partition, and let's say I have 4 consumers running, when the consumers subscribe to topics, will the 4 consumers divide the topics among themselves? (they would distribute partitions among themselves, but here 1 topic = 1 partition)

Would the above setup mean that for each table, the generated events on the topic will always be executed in order because there's at most 1 consumer acting on the topic at the same time?

I'm currently trying to get Kafka to restrict 1 partition per topic, and have 2 consumers. But the 2 consumers seem to pick up different topics every now and then and not be 'sticky' to the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there are 4 topics, 1 partition in each topic and 4 consumers, the consumers will evenly distribute the partitions among themselves which will result in 1 topic per consumer.

However, to get a "sticky assignment" you would need to give the consumer groups **static group IDs**. Otherwise, when there are failures and a rebalance is triggered, the consumer can be assigned a different partition (in this case a different topic).